# Can Theta be greater than 360 degrees in this equation?

Tags: kinematics

I have a quick question regarding Rotational Motion. I understand the equation

x = r (theta)

and I know that theta represents the Angular Displacement for a circle but what if the linear distance traveled is greater than the circumference of the circle.

Specifically, say that there was a cart rolling down the side walk and that the wheels to the cart had a circumference of 12 cm. I understand that if the cart only traveled a linear distance of 6 cm then the angular displacement would be 180 degrees but what if the car traveled more than 12 cm (the circumference of the cart), would my angular displacement be greater than 360?

Sorry if this is not as clear as possible, I am having a difficult time understanding it. Also, if I'm wrong or misguided in my initial assumptions please let me know.

Thanks for the help SE!
Ghost koi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. This is in some sense parallel to the distance v displacement question in linear motion. It's true that, at the end of it all, the angle difference between the final and initial configuration can't be more than 360 degrees or $2 \pi$ radians or whatever. But the angle that was traveled through--which is really the important thing for your purpose here--can certainly be more than that. Usually the reason we restrict angles to lie in a particular region, like 0 and 360, is that an angle $\theta + 360 = \theta$ for all intents and purposes. In this situation, however, the situation with $\theta = \theta_0$ and $\theta = \theta_0 + 360$ are distinguishable, so it's sensible to talk about the two as different angles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be greater than 360°.

Because what you basically do is you calculate $\frac{TraveledDistance}{circumference}$ . In your example this quotient is 0.5, but it can be also larger than 1.